# Injection and Surjection

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In each part of this problem, give examples of sets A,B,C and functions f : A → B and g : B → C satisfying the indicated properties.

a) g is not injective but g ◦ f is injective.

b) f is not surjective but g ◦ f is surjective.

Suggestion: Work with sets having at most 3 elements.

For a.) Would F(1,2)=1 and G(1,2,3)=2,3 work?

For b.) Would F(1,2,3)=2,3 and G(1)=1  work?

Im looking for some feedback? And I cannot figure out the sets A,B,C?

Answer (score 1):

Take $A= \big \{1,2 \big \}, B= \big \{1,2,3 \big \}, C= \big \{1,2 \big \}$. Define
$f:A \rightarrow B, g:B \rightarrow C$ by 
\begin{align}
f(1)=1, f(2)=2
\end{align}
\begin{align}
g(1)=1, g(2)=2, g(3)=3
\end{align}
Then $g$ is not injective and $f$ is not surjective.
And $g \circ f:A \rightarrow C$ is given by
\begin{align}
(g \circ f)(1) =g(f(1)) =g(1)=1 \\
(g \circ f)(2) =g(f(2)) =g(2)=2
\end{align}
Note that $g \circ f$ is both injective and surjective.